# Microsoft Sharepoint adds "External Class" to my CSS after saving a rich field

Tags: html, css, class, sharepoint, external

So I am pretty new with Sharepoint but I am experienced enough with HTML and CSS. I currently made this mini html application to change some pictures of the hyperlinks on hover and it works fine if I run it on a normal browser/outside of sharepoint.

Now the problem is as follows, I go into sharepoint and I write my code in a rich field (which gives me the option to embed html into it) and it doesn't work. It would work in "edit mode" but not after saving it. Also after saving the HTML code, it generates something called "External class" next to each of my CSS objects as shown below. Is that the reason why my code is not working after saving? What is sharepoint doing to my HTML code? Is there a way to fix this? I would appreciate some help on the matter.

**Original:**

```css
            <style type="text/css">
                        #map
                        {
                                   width:663px;
                                   height:715px;
                                   background-image:url("/sites/00172/SiteAssets/Germany1-Standard.png");
                        }
                        #Bremen
                        {
                                   position:absolute;
                                   width:37px;
                                   height:53px;
                                    top:359px;
                                   left:243px;
                                   background-image:none;
                        }
                        #Berlin
                        {
                                   position:absolute;
                                   width:35px;
                                   height:55px;
                                   top:393px;
                                   left:550px;
              background-image:none;
                        }
                        
                        #Coburg
                        {
                                   position:absolute;
                                   width:41px;
                                   height:54px;
                                   top:605px;
                                   left:382px;
              background-image:none;
                        }
                        #Hallstadt-Bamberg
                        {
                                   position:absolute;
                                   width:43px;
                                   height:51px;
                                   top:659px;
                                   left:368px;
                                   background-image:none;
                        }
                        
                        #Bremen:hover
  {
   background-image:url("/sites/00172/SiteAssets/Germany1-Bremen.png");
  }
  
  #Berlin:hover
  {
   background-image:url("/sites/00172/SiteAssets/Germany1-Berlin.png");
  }
  
  #Coburg:hover
  {
   background-image:url("/sites/00172/SiteAssets/Germany1-Coburg.png");
  }
  
  #Hallstadt-Bamberg:hover
  {
   background-image:url("/sites/00172/SiteAssets/Germany1-Hallstadt.png");

  }
            </style>
```

```html
            <div id="map">
                        <a href="/sites/00172/Lists/Calendar01/calendar.aspx" title="Bremen" id="Bremen">
                        <a href="/sites/00172/Lists/Calendar02/calendar.aspx" title="Berlin" id="Berlin">
                        <a href="/sites/00172/Lists/Calender03/calendar.aspx" title="Coburg" id="Coburg">
                        <a href="/sites/00172/Lists/Calendar04/calendar.aspx" title="Hallstadt-Bamberg" id="Hallstadt-Bamberg">
            </div>
```

**After Saving in Sharepoint:**

```css
            <style unselectable="on">
AFC97320FBA74F4E88F2B1AD1F833E02 .ExternalClass #map {
width:663px;
height:715px;
}
 
AFC97320FBA74F4E88F2B1AD1F833E02 .ExternalClass #Bremen {
position:absolute;
width:37px;
height:53px;
top:83px;
left:209px;
}
 
AFC97320FBA74F4E88F2B1AD1F833E02 .ExternalClass #Berlin {
position:absolute;
width:35px;
height:55px;
top:118px;
left:516px;
}
 
AFC97320FBA74F4E88F2B1AD1F833E02 .ExternalClass #Coburg {
position:absolute;
width:41px;
height:54px;
top:605px;
left:382px;
}
 
AFC97320FBA74F4E88F2B1AD1F833E02 .ExternalClass #Hallstadt-Bamberg {
position:absolute;
width:43px;
height:51px;
top:209px;
left:83px;
}
 
AFC97320FBA74F4E88F2B1AD1F833E02 .ExternalClass #Bremen:hover {

}
 
AFC97320FBA74F4E88F2B1AD1F833E02 .ExternalClass #Berlin:hover {

}
 
AFC97320FBA74F4E88F2B1AD1F833E02 .ExternalClass #Coburg:hover {

}
 
AFC97320FBA74F4E88F2B1AD1F833E02 .ExternalClass #Hallstadt-Bamberg:hover {

}
</style>
```

```html
<div id="map" unselectable="on">
                        <a title="Bremen" id="Bremen" href="/sites/00172/Lists/Calendar01/calendar.aspx" unselectable="on">
                        </a><a title="Berlin" id="Berlin" href="/sites/00172/Lists/Calendar02/calendar.aspx" unselectable="on">
                        </a><a title="Coburg" id="Coburg" href="/sites/00172/Lists/Calendar03/calendar.aspx" unselectable="on">
                        </a><a title="Hallstadt-Bamberg" id="Hallstadt-Bamberg" href="/sites/00172/Lists/Calendar04/calendar.aspx" unselectable="on">
            </a></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you enter HTML directly into a Content Editor web part, SharePoint does some extra work to "sanitize" your HTML/CSS and prevent naming collisions.

If you want SharePoint to leave your HTML/CSS/JavaScript alone, instead of entering it directly into the Content Editor web part, save it as a text or HTML file in a document library, then use the Content Editor web part's "content link" property to embed the desired file. This will leave your original markup and code untouched.